# Can RPL be different from DPL on x86 machines?

Tags: x86, memory-segmentation

I was reading a [blog post](http://static.duartes.org/img/blogPosts/segmentProtection.png) on x86 segmentation protection. Can RPL be different from DPL and if so what is the use-case for this?

Answer (score 2):

They can be different and that's intentional.

The idea is that when the OS/kernel does something on behalf of user code, it could access memory using user code's privileges (`RPL` would reflect, well, the `Requestor Privilege Level`, user code's level). If they are insufficient, an exception fails the operation. If this (or similar) mechanism isn't there, user code may subvert the OS/kernel by somehow requesting an operation to be performed on its behalf and the operation would be performed by the kernel with its, kernel's, privileges. That's where you get [EOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation).

For more info on segments, go to the source, the CPU manuals from Intel. It's all there.

Comment: Can you please make your example more concrete by specifying the CPL, RPL and DPL values with the kernel code in ring 0 and user-code in ring 3.

Comment: DPL is whatever happens to be in the descriptor of the segment the kernel is accessing (e.g. could be kernel (normally, 0) or user (3)). Kernel's CPL is 0 (pretty much always). RPL in the segment selector that's being used to access the segment is the level of the requestor. If the requestor is user, it's 3. If the requestor is kernel, it's typically 0.

Comment: So in your example max(CPL, RPL) = 0 and DPL can be 0 or 3. So, the kernel can access any data segment it wants to. But you are saying that the kernel uses an RPL of 3 when executing code on behalf of another user to avoid accidentally changing something in some other user's code. But, if I set RPL = 3, I then cannot data segments belonging to the kernel (which will have DPL 0). I am confused

Comment: In my example max(CPL, RPL) is either 0 (when the requestor is also kernel code) or 3 (when the requestor is user code). That's the whole point, user code should not read or write kernel data, directly or indirectly. Protection!

Comment: Thanks alexey!!..The way you have described is much better and easier to understand than what it is written in Intel manuals.